# asp.net vallidation on database save button

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, button, save

I use a button to save textbox en dropdown valves to a database 
but the problem is its for a reservation system for my cousin and he has a maximum of 50 seats.

My question is can i put in some kind of validation or count that give back a massage when the
maxiumum places is reached or surpased to the one that wants to make a reservation.

here is my button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BT-1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from  OpdrachtGever";
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "OpdrachtGever");
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].NewRow();
            drow["Naam"] = TextBox1.Text;
            drow["Adres"] = TextBox2.Text;
            drow["PostCode"] = TextBox3.Text;
            drow["WoonPlaats"] = TextBox4.Text;
            drow["TelefoonNummer"] = TextBox5.Text;
            drow["EmailAdres"] = TextBox6.Text;
            drow["AantalPersonen"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

            ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].Rows.Add(drow);
            da.Update(ds, "OpdrachtGever");
            string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
        alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
       </script>;";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the number of rows in the OpdrachtGever table after filling the dataset:

```
da.Fill(ds, "OpdrachtGever");
// Check booked count
int totalBooked = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].Rows)
{
   totalBooked += Int32.Parse(row["AantalPersonen"]);
}

if (totalBooked >= 50)
{
//show error and return
}
```

Comment: the problem is that someone can give up with how mutch pepole he wants to come when they make the reservation so that valve needs to be subtracted from 50 and then when the next reservation is put in the vavle from the dropdown list Aantalpersonen needs to be subtracted from the number that came from the previous subtraction.

Comment: I've changed my answer to calculate the total count of reservations

Comment: There is another problem:
When two clients run this code at the same time, it can be that both path the check and then both insert the row to the DataSet.

Comment: now it give back an error  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

Comment: To prevent multiple clients passing the check at the same time you should make totalbooked a static class variable.

Comment: I changed var to DataRow in the foreach loop. But I agree with @Dannydust that there could be concurrency problems with this solution. You should consider using some form of transaction handling to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: the for each loop give erros as welit gives back
Error 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'.
Error 1 :The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments i am gratefull for the help but i cant get these errors away with the code you profided @HåkanFahlstedt

Comment: now the for loop works but i got the question if i cant put in an date en time field to the reservation so i did but i cant getthe save button to write the to a database table main problem i think is because the row whre it need to be put is an a separte table called "Reservering" Colmn name is BeginTijdDatum but i can notthink of a goed working code to save all the data at once the opdrachtgever and the time date to reservering can some one shed some light on it